# Why there difference in training accuracy when using sklearn pipeline and not using it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, random-forest

Here I'm talking about training accuracy that we see in classification report.

I trained a model using sklearn's pipeline and I got acuracy  78%. After that I traind model without using pipelineI got accuray 98%. I have a doubt that why there so much difference between accuracy?

Training model using pipepilne:
Functions for text preprocessing:

```
def text_preprocess(mess):
    #nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]
    #nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
    stopwords = list(string.punctuation) + nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
    mess = str(mess)
    nopunc = mess.lower()
    nopunc = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))', 'URL', nopunc) # remove URLs
    nopunc = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', nopunc) # remove usernames
    nopunc = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', nopunc) # remove the # in #hashtag
    nopunc = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(nopunc) # remove repeated characters (helloooooooo into hello)
    #return [word for word in nopunc if word not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
    return [word for word in nopunc if word not in stopwords]

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_preprocess)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))
])
```

Training without pipeline:

```
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_preprocess).fit(train['Sentimenttext'])
messages_bow = bow_transformer.transform(train['Sentimenttext'])
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)
messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
spam_detect_model = RandomForestClassifier().fit(messages_tfidf, train['Sentiment'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random\_state parameter in classification models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944725/random-state-parameter-in-classification-models)

Comment: No that is all about estimators and here I have kept same number of estimators than also i'm getting different accuracy

Comment: I think you are missing the key part. Use same random_state seed value in both cases.